# Reference request for positive matrices

Tags: matrices, reference-request, stochastic-processes

I would much appreciate someone suggest me a text book which covers stochastic matrices in depth with all relevant theories.Thanks

Comment: Note that in linear algebra literature, the term **"stochastic matrix"** usually refers to an entrywise nonnegative matrix whose row sums or column sums are equal to 1. This is different from a **"random matrix"**, whose entries follow some statistical distribution. Please modify your question if you mean random matrices rather than stochastic matrices.

Comment: @user1551 This refers to stochastic matrices